# CSS increase opacity of nested span tag

Tags: html, css

I have some text within a div that I do not want the opacity to affect; I want the text to be 100% fully opaque but the background color to be 50% opaque.

So far I have been unsuccessful.

HTML:

```
        <div class='photo'>
            <div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'></a></div>
            <div class='photo-name'><span>Name</span></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.photo {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 298px;
    height: 298px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.photo-name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.photo-name > span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/w71677jm/

Comment: Is the html structure inflexible?

Comment: It is not responsive at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RGBA color

```js
.photo-name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color: #666666;*/
    background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}
```

Comment: Dang, wasn't there when I started answering this. :-)

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Robert. How's this.

The solution is

```
rgba(102,102,102, 0.5);
```

rgba = red,green,blue,alpa channel

(102,102,102) = #666666

0.5 = your 50% transparent

Check out the SO Snippet below or this forked fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha7sb4rb/)

Hope this helps!

Best,

Tim

```css
.photo-name {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 175px;
 width: 300px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.5);
 color: #fff;
    padding-top:.5em;
    padding-bottom:.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class='photo'>
    <div class='image'>
        <a href='#'>
            <img src='https://i.imgur.com/PC68FSTb.jpg' alt='profile picture' width='300' height='300'>
        </a>
    </div>
 <div class='photo-name'>
        <span>Name</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobertRocha In what way? In the snippet the text background is 50% transparent and the text is solid white not transparency. Am I missing a requirement? What browser are you using?

Comment: Ok. I could not tell since the thing is out of alignment,

Comment: Just realign the css positioning. Glad I could help.